# CORS policy error with Next.js v13 and Firebase: Blocked access to site.webmanifest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

Bacground:
I am building a website using Next.js version 13 along with Firebase, and I have deployed it on Vercel.

While checking the console, I encountered two CORS policy errors related to my site.webmanifest file.

I have replaced my actual website URL with https://example.com in the error messages below:

error 1:

```
Access to manifest at 'https://example.com/site.webmanifest' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
example.com/site.webmanifest:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

error 2:

```
Access to internal resource at 'https://example.com/site.webmanifest' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I'm not sure where to address this issue.
Should I be looking at my frontend or backend code?
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

What I've tried:
Googled and found out some comments about: set header with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

Comment: There are no CORS restrictions on requests to the same origin.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial might help. I found that it addressed some of my CORS issues but I still need to resolve CORS errors with auth
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4-2K7nFf7s